# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tokenize, text-classification, stemming, lemmatization

**I am working on text classification using Naive Bayes & SVM. And my dataset is from extracted FAQs about COVID**

I am trying to change all the text to lower case. This is required as python interprets 'dog' and 'DOG' differently:
Corpus['Question'] = [entry.lower() for entry in Corpus['Question']]

and I get the following error:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
6
7 # Step - b : Change all the text to lower case. This is required as python interprets 'dog' and 'DOG' differently
----> 8 Corpus['Question'] = [entry.lower() for entry in Corpus['Question']]
9
10 # Step - c : Tokenization : In this each entry in the corpus will be broken into set of words

in (.0)
6
7 # Step - b : Change all the text to lower case. This is required as python interprets 'dog' and 'DOG' differently
----> 8 Corpus['Question'] = [entry.lower() for entry in Corpus['Question']]
9
10 # Step - c : Tokenization : In this each entry in the corpus will be broken into set of words

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that you're applying the function `lower()` to a list, but actually it can only be applied to a string.

The code you show is not complete, so I can only guess. Assuming that `Corpus['Question']` is a list of *tokenized* sentences, i.e. it's *a list of list of strings*, the following should work:

```
Corpus['Question'] = [[word.lower() for word in question] for question in Corpus['Question']]
```